# Multiple storyboards for different iPhone sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have the below code set up in appDel.m in didFinishLaunching. 
I currently have 2 storyboards iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. The issues is the code I am using is not selecting the iPhone 5 storyboard, it always defaults to the iPhone 6.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBd;
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
result = CGSizeMake(result.width, result.height * scale);

NSLog(@"The Result height is %f",result.height);

if (result.height == 1136) {
    storyBd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"i5Story" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initView = [storyBd instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initView];
}else if (result.height == 1334){
     storyBd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"i6Story" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initView = [storyBd instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initView];
}
```

Comment: What is the log output of `result.height`?

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the height isn't `1136` it is `568`. You don't look for the retina height (1136), just the normal "1x" pixel size.

Also you really shouldn't do this, rather use auto layout and make one storyboard.

Comment: But the OP is multiplying the screen height by the screen scale so the result would be in pixels, not points.

Comment: Ohh !! okay, yeah but my vc is too complicated for auto layout struggled for weeks trying to get it to work properly.

Comment: And that condition will never count on new devices with new dimensions on the market, so you really should consider using universal philosophy, like single storyboard conventions as sbarow marks.

Comment: Yeah i guess so, will give it another try. And I do agree, just having so much difficulty getting it right.